# can't add chrome extension ID to Firebase Authentication section

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

Firebase show success notification but this chrome extension domain did't show in list of authorized domains. I tested  in other project in other account but getting same problem. let's see the photos
[image]
[image]

Comment: This error has occurred for 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has fixed this bug after 4 days